# how the Laravel "Storage::download()" method works under the hood?

Tags: php, laravel, file, download

I can't see this method in facade and in related to this facade class. Can anyone tell me how this "magic" actually works or at least provide some links with explanation?

Answer (score 0):

As per laravel source code that method comes from Symfony component and it creates a streamed download response for a given file.

```
 /**
 * Create a streamed download response for a given file.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string|null  $name
 * @param  array|null  $headers
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse
 */
public function download($path, $name = null, array $headers = [])
{
    return $this->response($path, $name, $headers, 'attachment');
}
```

ref:https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5398fbbbf81ed842cf0430b278f07eb0f869cf8f/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L205